# Nested Data Structures: Why is my Hash turning into an Array of an Array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

For an assignment I am working on, I'm trying to sort words in a piece of text by frequency of words in the text. I have a function that almost accomplishes what I'd like to do but not quite. Below is my code:

```
require 'pry'
def top_words(words)
  word_count = Hash.new(0)
  words = words.split(" ")
  words.each { |word| word_count[word] += 1 }
  word_count = word_count.sort_by do |words, frequencies|
    frequencies
  end
  binding.pry
  word_count.reverse!
  word_count.each { |word, frequencies| puts word + " " + frequencies.to_s }
end

words = "1st RULE: You do not talk about FIGHT CLUB.
2nd RULE: You DO NOT talk about FIGHT CLUB.
3rd RULE: If someone says 'stop' or goes limp, taps out the fight is over.
4th RULE: Only two guys to a fight.
5th RULE: One fight at a time.
6th RULE: No shirts, no shoes.
7th RULE: Fights will go on as long as they have to.
8th RULE: If this is your first night at FIGHT CLUB, you HAVE to fight."
```

For some reason, the sort_by method above my binding.pry is changing the structure of my Hash into an array of an array. Why?
What I'd like to do is to sort the words within a hash and then grab the top three words from the Hash. I've yet to figure out how to do this but I'm pretty sure I can do this once I've sorted the array of an array problem.

Now, I suppose I could grab them using .each and array[0].each { |stuff| puts stuff[0] + stuff[1] } but I don't think that is the most efficient way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason, the `sort_by` method above my binding.pry is changing the structure of my Hash into an array of an array. Why?

Explanation is below :

[`sort_by { |obj| block } → array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) method give always *array*.

> The current implementation of `sort_by` generates an array of *tuples* containing the original collection element and the mapped value. This makes sort_by fairly expensive when the *keysets* are simple.

Now in your case `word_count` is a `Hash` object, thus `sort_by` is giving you like - `[[key1,val],[key2,val2],..]`. This is the reason you are getting *array of array*.

> What I'd like to do is to sort the words within a hash and then grab the top three words from the Hash. I've yet to figure out how to do this but I'm pretty sure I can do this once I've sorted the array of an array problem.

Yes, possible.

```
sorted_array_of_array = word_count.sort_by do |words, frequencies| frequencies }
top_3_hash = Hash[ sorted_array_of_array.last(3) ]
```

I would write the code as below :

```
def top_words(words)
  # splitting the string words on single white space to create word array.
  words = words.split(" ")
  # creating a hash, which will have key as word and value is the number of times,
  # that word occurred in a sentence.
  word_count = words.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |word,hash| hash[word] += 1 }
  # sorting the hash, to get a descending order sorted array of array
  sorted_array_of_array = word_count.sort_by { |words, frequencies| frequencies }
  # top 3 word/frequency is taken from the sorted list. Now reading them from last
  # to show the output as first top,second top and so on..
  sorted_array_of_array.last(3).reverse_each do |word, frequencies| 
    puts "#{word} has #{frequencies}"
  end
end
```